# xpathSApply webscrape returns NULL

Tags: r, xpath

Using my trusty firebug and firepath plug-ins I'm trying to scrape some data.

```
require(XML)

url <- "http://www.hkjc.com/english/racing/display_sectionaltime.asp?racedate=25/05/2008&Raceno=2&All=0"
tree <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
t <- xpathSApply(tree, "//html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/font/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font", xmlValue) # works
```

This works!  t now contains `"Meeting Date: 25/05/2008, Sha Tin\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"`

If I try to capture the first sectional time of 29.4 thusly:

```
t <- xpathSApply(tree, "//html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/font/a/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]", xmlValue) # doesn't work

t contains NULL.
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?  Many thanks.

Comment: scrapeR depends on XML (and RCurl)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I can't find that first sectional time of 29.4. The one I see on the page you linked is 24.5 or I'm misunderstanding what you are looking for.

Here's a way of grabbing that one using `rvest` and SelectorGadget for Chrome:

```
library(rvest)
html <- read_html(url) 
t <- html %>%
    html_nodes(".bigborder table tr+ tr td:nth-child(2) font") %>%
    html_text(trim = T) 

> t
[1] "24.5"
```

This differs a bit from your approach but I hope it helps. Not sure how to properly scrape the meeting time that way, but this at least works:

```
mt <- html %>%
    html_nodes("font > table font") %>%
    html_text(trim = T)  

> mt
 [1] "Meeting Date: 25/05/2008, Sha Tin"                      "4 - 1200M - (060-040) - Turf - A Course - Good To Firm"
 [3] "MONEY TALKS HANDICAP"                                   "Race\tTime :"                                           
 [5] "(24.5)"                                                 "(48.1)"                                                
 [7] "(1.10.3)"                                               "Sectional Time :"                                      
 [9] "24.5"                                                   "23.6"                                                  
[11] "22.2"                                                  
> mt[1]
[1] "Meeting Date: 25/05/2008, Sha Tin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the comments just after the `<a>` may be throwing you off.

```
<a name="Race1">
  <!-- test0 table start -->
  <table class="bigborder" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="760">...
  <!--0 table End -->
  <!-- test1 table start -->
  <br>
  <br>
</a>
```

This seems to work:

```
t <- xpathSApply(tree, '//tr/td/font[text()="Sectional Time : "]/../following-sibling::td[1]/font', xmlValue)
```

You might want to try something a little less fragile then that long direct path.

**Update**

If you are after all of the times in the "1st Sec." column: 29.4, 28.7, etc...

```
t <- xpathSApply(
  tree,
  "//tr/td[starts-with(.,'1st Sec.')]/../following-sibling::*[position() mod 2 = 0]/td[1]",
  xmlValue
)
```

Looks for the "1st Sec." column, then jump up to its row, grab every other row's 1st td value.

```
[1] "29.4   "
[2] "28.7   "
[3] "29.2   "
[4] "29.0   "
[5] "29.3   "
[6] "28.2   "
[7] "29.5   "
[8] "29.5   "
[9] "30.1   "
[10] "29.8   "
[11] "29.6   "
[12] "29.9   "
[13] "29.1   "
[14] "29.8   "
```

*I've removed all the extra whitespace (\r\n\t\t...) for display purposes here.*

If you wanted to make it a little more dynamic, you could grab the column value under "1st Sec." or any other column. Replace

```
/td[1]
```

with

```
td[count(//tr/td[starts-with(.,'1st Sec.')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

Using that, you could update the name of the column, and grab the corresponding values. For all "3rd Sec." times:

```
"//tr/td[starts-with(.,'3rd Sec.')]/../following-sibling::*[position() mod 2 = 0]/td[count(//tr/td[starts-with(.,'3rd Sec.')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]"

[1] "23.3   "
[2] "23.7   "
[3] "23.3   "
[4] "23.8   "
[5] "23.7   "
[6] "24.5   "
[7] "24.1   "
[8] "24.0   "
[9] "24.1   "
[10] "24.1   "
[11] "23.9   "
[12] "23.9   "
[13] "24.3   "
[14] "24.0   "
```

Comment: Thanks JRD and Khl4v.  My bad, I had the wrong url (I have amended the question to point to the second race).  This works for grabbing the first sectional time above the table, I was after the first (and all actually) sectional time in the table.  So 29.4 in race 2.  I've tried readHTMLTable, the output is too big to work with easily.  The rest of the data on the page yields to nice short cut methods, s <- xpathSApply(tree, "//div[@class='table_eng_small_text_t4']", xmlValue) grabs nearly everything.  But the pesky sectional times in the table resisting my efforts.

Comment: JRD a more elegant approach and it works perfectly.  Thanks.  Are there any Xpath internet resources that you could recommend?  (Trying and failing to see exactly how this works, // - find all the nodes, find all the <tr>s, find all the <td> children whose name begins with "1st Sec.", and find a parent ?! now I'm getting lost.)

Comment: The xpath documentation is a bit sparse outside of the official spec. A lot of it is just trial and error. The online fiddlers are good test beds to try out ideas, e.g. [xPath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath).